# How to add both TapDetector and HasTappable mixin to the game class in Flame Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flame

I want to add Tap functionality to both the game class itself and components, but cannot add both `TapDetector` and `HasTappable` mixins to the game class! What approach should be taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `HasTappables` mixin on your `FlameGame` class you don't need a `TapDetector`, you can just override:

```dart
  void onTapCancel(int pointerId);
  void onTapDown(int pointerId, TapDownInfo info);
  void onTapUp(int pointerId, TapUpInfo info);
```

since they exist in `HasTappables`.

And remember to call super when you override them (your IDE will remind you too).